# How to solve url canonicalization?

Tags: seo, canonical-link

The url http://www.example.com/ and http://www.example.com/index.html both display the same web page. But search engine treats them as 2 different urls. Hence there is a split in the page rank and affects SEO.

Possible solutions I got after web search:

```
1.Use DirectoryIndex index.html in the .htaccess file.
```

This tells the search engine that http://www.example.com/ and http://www.example.com/index.html are same.

Issue I am facing: DirectoryIndex index.html in the .htaccess file expects that all sub-folders also have and index.html file. Ex. if there is a folder "blog" in the root directory which has no index.html file in it, then the url 
"http://www.example.com/blog/" throws index not found error.

```
2.using 301 redirect. Redirect http://www.example.com/index.html to http://www.example.com/
```

Issue: redirections increase load time. It is not a good practice.

Please suggest which solution is better? I doubt if the 1st one is a solution or not.
Also, if I have to redirect, redirecting http://www.example.com/index.html to http://www.example.com/ is better or vice-versa with regard to SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html). This will solve the problem easily. You could also do a 301 redirect from the index.html to the / if necessary as that would also accomplish the same thing.

Comment: the example site is "http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish" but I have root(http://www.example.com) and index.html. will this solution work if i just add <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com"> inside index.html file?

Comment: @Sangam254 - Yes.  You want `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/" />`